# How to read graph data from titan db?

Tags: java, titan

I have a titan graph database. I am given a task to read data from this graph database using Rexster or any tool or any API.  I have no idea how to read the graph data and later convert into java objects.
I believe the data when read, will be in JSON format and then we can convert it into java objects. The main challenge is how to read data from titandb..Any help is appreciated..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking.  Is this question about "how to read data from titandb"?  The [Getting Started](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/getting-started.html) guide for Titan tells you how to connect to a graph and read the data which is pretty straightforward.  can you further define your problem please?

Comment: i was trying to load titan graphs through rexster. My graph is sitting on hbase which is in a remote machine. Step 1: I downloaded rexster 2.4.0 and titan server 0.4.4 separately. Step 2: Edited rexster.xml as per my requirement. Step 3: copied all titan libs to rexster libs. Step 4: I am running this on windows, so i ran bin\rexster.bat --start. Unfortunately, it was giving me a huge error...may be it was not finding the libraries and could not load graph...Check your XML file.

Solution: I downloaded titan-rexster-server 2.5.0, edited the XML file (same as Step 2)and it worked.

Comment: Question: 1. I am still confused why didn't it ran before since XML file was same ? 2. Now i can see my graph in DogHouse, i want to fire some gremlin queries to find their vertices and edges and later create a JAVA code doing the same. How should i connect to my graph through gremlin and JAVA ? Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your "question 1" in the comments, your `rexster.xml` was not likely to be the problem in that case.  `rexster.xml` doesn't define the classpath and you likely just had some things out of place.  I can't fully explain it otherwise unfortunately as the issue sounds very specific to the particulars of your environment.

As for "question 2" in the comments and I guess what was your original question, you have Titan running against hbase and you have Rexster running.  You now have numerous options for how to connect with Gremlin:

1. Maybe you just use [Gremlin through java](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java) using a GremlinPipeline or a ScriptEngine embedding.
2. Maybe you issue some requests to Rexster via the [REST API](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Basic-REST-API) and [Gremlin Extension](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Gremlin-Extension)
3. How about using [RexPro](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/RexPro-Java)?